In Oracle what is the default data type of varchar2, CHAR or BYTE?
In oracle you can apparently specify if you want the varchar2 data type length to be represented as byte length or char length.
varchar2(10 byte)
vs
varchar2(10 char)
My question is, if I don't specify 'byte' or 'char', but I do specify a length, is the default length char or byte??
varchar2(10)
NOTE: the following test shows that varchar2(10), when attempting to save more than 10 standard characters.
DECLARE
  varchar2_10 varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  varchar2_10 := '1234567890'; -- THIS works
  -- varchar2_10 := '1234567890123' -- THIS generates an error.
END

I believe the default is CHAR ... however I didn't ever find a definitive answer.

After typing up this question I decided I could probably answer it for myself.
I did a little more research about character sets etc... but still didn't get any very valuable information back.
The answer is BYTE is the default, (but please note the important UPDATE at the end of this answer*).
Here's what I did to figure this out:

Made a table with 3 columns, each using one of the 3 different ways to represent a varchar2 column data type (CODE TO FOLLOW)
Inserted data into that table in various ways
First I attempted to insert '123456789012345' into each, as a control... this worked for all 3 (as expected)
Next I inserted '1234567890123456' into each... all 3 gave an error of ORA-12899: value too large for column ...
Finally I used a multibyte character and I attempted to enter 15 of them into each. The result was an error from the default (varchar2(15) and from the BYTE specified (varchar2(15 byte).

Therefore, it seems the default is BYTE.
CODE:
CREATE TABLE XX_DELETE_ME
(
    numeric_key NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,avarchar2_15 varchar2(15)
    ,avarchar2_15_char varchar2(15 char)
    ,avarchar2_15_byte varchar2(15 byte)
);

-- error on avarchar2_15
INSERT INTO XX_DELETE_ME(avarchar2_15, avarchar2_15_char, avarchar2_15_byte)
VALUES('æææææææææææææææ','æææææææææææææææ','æææææææææææææææ');

-- error on avarchar2_15_byte
INSERT INTO XX_DELETE_ME(avarchar2_15, avarchar2_15_char, avarchar2_15_byte)
VALUES('æææææææ','æææææææææææææææ','æææææææææææææææ');

-- no error
INSERT INTO XX_DELETE_ME(avarchar2_15, avarchar2_15_char, avarchar2_15_byte)
VALUES('æææææææ','æææææææææææææææ','æææææææ');

NOTE: As additional support for this I tried the following:
DESCRIBE XX_DELET_ME;
The result shows the varchar2(15) and varchar2(15 byte) the same... but the char as "VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)"
*UPDATE!
@MTO has informed me that technically the answer is: 
'The default type of length for a varchar2 is whatever the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter is set to'.
AND, the default is BYTE

This is (technically) wrong - As stated in the linked duplicate, the default is whatever the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter is set to. The default value for NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS is BYTE but if anyone changes it at either the instance- or session-level then you will not have the default behaviour.

Thanks @MT0 I will update this to reflect the additional information.
However, as much as this might be a duplicate answer wise, I diligently searched and there's no way I would have found the question, and therefore the answers when the title of the question is as obscure as it is. So marking as a dupe is somewhat valuable but also not essential: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

I searched for [oracle] varchar2 char byte and that was the top result. Those search terms are obvious from the question and the title of the duplicate is fairly descriptive of the problem (if not particularly verbose).

Hey @MTO... yeah that's absolutely not the text I would have used to search with... and I still wouldn't even knowing the answer.
I don't care about reputation so closing the question is not really a problem from me... as I believe others who use more natural language in their searches will find this and get the answer they need.
Please read the blog post from one of the founders of stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/
